# Array of Components in Forms Designer

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, components

Is there any good way in Windows Forms Designer to have an array (or other collection) of similar components defined?  You can check "GenerateMember", which will give you a unique named member in code to reference, but what if I want that generated member to be one of a list of some sort, so that I can iterate through them easily?  The only way I can think of is to create a new list on load, and the manually add all the already-generated members to that list, which is tedious and redundant.  I thought about editing the code that generates these components, but it's inside that auto-generated "Do not modify" section, and I'm afraid any change I make there will be overwritten any time I make other changes to the form.  Does the Form Designer just not have this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply cast "this" (the form) to a "Control", and then examine it's "ControlCollection" property- a collection containing the form's controls. Eg.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var myControlList = ((Control)this).Controls;
    }
}
```

Unless I am missing something...

Comment: Hmm, this woks, but it seems a little hackish - First I have to cast the container (not "this" but a TableLayoutPanel here), then I have to cast each of the elements as well (they're PictureBoxes in this case)  I always feel weird when there's that much type-casting involved, seems a little "unsafe", like I should be putting null-checks on everything just to be sure, but if that's the only way to do it, I guess it's okay.

Comment: Remember, casting isn't the same as "conversion" - it's only getting a reference to an existing interface, and so performance isn't an issue. But I am not quite understanding why you need an array anyway? Can you just iterate over the container's children? I may need to see some code to have a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's actually nested several layers deep - a table within a table within a table, and I only care about the deepest one in this case.  I've since refactored so that instead of having 90 PictureBoxes all pre-made in the Forms Designer I'm now creating them manually.  (The list was becoming somewhat unwieldy.)  It still seems like I'm copying a lot of references to get down to that level, which seems wrong somehow (coming from a C/C++ workflow where you had to manage your own memory).  It may be only 4 bytes per, but it still seems slightly inefficient.

Comment: If we're talking about memory, 90 pointers is nothing. 90 PictureBoxes, on the other hand, is a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put them inside a Panel and then iterate through its controls.